# pixi.js PIXI.Texture.from() can't add images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, pixi.js

I'm using react with pixi.js to development a simple web game

and I want to add some images to pixi.js from local directory

here is the website I studied

https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-basic/container.js

and here are the codes

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
import React from 'react'

export default class PixiTestPage extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        //Create a Pixi Application
        const app = new PIXI.Application({
            backgroundColor: 0x1099bb
        });

        //Add the canvas that Pixi automatically created for you to the HTML document
        document.body.appendChild(app.view);

        const texture = PIXI.Texture.from("./bunny.png")
        const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

        bunny.anchor.set(0.5)
        bunny.x = app.screen.width / 2;
        bunny.y = app.screen.height / 2;  
        app.stage.addChild(bunny);  
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

but the browser keep showing error message
[Uncaught (in promise)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKBmx.png)

same as I use @inlet/react-pixi

https://reactpixi.org/

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
import React from 'react'
import { Stage, Sprite } from '@inlet/react-pixi';

export default class PixiTestPage extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Stage>
                    <Sprite image="./bunny.png" x={100} y={100} />
                </Stage>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the Uncaught (in promise) error still there

but when I using the url like

https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/bunny.png

it worked

how to use images in pixi.js with local directory?

here is the image path

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro5iG.png)

Comment: it depends on your local directory structure, if you are using absolute link, then it'll work, however if you switch to local, then you can take a look at the error link, `./bunny.png` might not be the right path, maybe `/bunny.png`. You need to play with it a bit.

Comment: I change to /bunny.png but still not working

Comment: same as the absolute link ...

Comment: Will it be the problem of the picture itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I forgot react must use import images...

so the solution is

```
import React from 'react'
import { Stage, Sprite } from '@inlet/react-pixi';
import bunny from './bunny.png'

export default class PixiTestPage extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Stage>
                    <Sprite image={bunny} x={100} y={100} />
                </Stage>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```